# What is the past counterpart for "scenario"

Tags: word-choice

Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scenario) says

> In this sense, scenarios should not be used to speculate on what has happened in the past.

Oxford advanced dictionary says

> 1. a description of how things might happen in the future.

So what pithy word should I use to describe an event that could have happened in the past?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Despite what Wikipedia may tell you, there is nothing preventing you from using *scenario* to refer to past events, especially if the actual circumstances are unknown or unclear: From NOAD:

> **scenario** |səˈne(ə)rēˌō; -ˈnär-|
> *noun* ( pl. -os)
> a written outline of a movie, novel, or stage work giving details of the plot and individual scenes : *imagine the scenarios for four short stories*.
> • a postulated sequence or development of events : *a possible scenario is that he was attacked after opening the front door*.
> • a setting, in particular for a work of art or literature : *the scenario is World War II*.

Note that the last two example usages concern themselves with past events.

**Addendum**

The Wikipedia link you reference no longer contains any prescriptive notion such as you mention. It does, however, say the following:

> Surviving scenarios from the Renaissance contain little other than character names, brief descriptions of action, and references to specific lazzi with no further explanation.

This is clearly a use of *scenario* in the context of the past.

Answer (score 1):

Calling it a *[counterfactual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_history)* is another possibility, historiographically speaking:

> **Counterfactual history**, also sometimes referred to as **virtual history**, is a form of historiography which attempts to answer "what if" questions known as counterfactuals. It seeks to explore history and historical incidents by means of extrapolating a timeline in which certain key historical events did not happen or had an outcome which was different from that which did in fact occur.

Comment: A counterfactual history virtually by definition is one *known* **not** *to have actually happened*. OP's usage is concerned with *possible, but not actually* **known** *to have happened*, which is a different thing.